# CosmicMind/Material - How to call pushViewController in NavigationDrawerController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, cosmicmind

I want to do pushViewController on rootViewController in current sample of `NavigationDrawerController` https://github.com/CosmicMind/Samples/blob/master/Projects/Programmatic/NavigationDrawerController/NavigationDrawerController/RootViewController.swift

and as well as in `TransitionedViewController` https://github.com/CosmicMind/Samples/blob/master/Projects/Programmatic/NavigationDrawerController/NavigationDrawerController/TransitionedViewController.swift

Nothing is happening if I call `navigationController?.pushViewController(MyController(), animated: true)`

If attach NavigationController to rootViewController then center rootViewController will not change on tap of leftViewController

```
(navigationDrawerController?.rootViewController as? ToolbarController)?.transition(to: TransitionedViewController(), completion: closeNavigationDrawer)
```

This is because `rootViewController` doesn't have `NavigationController`. If I attach `AppToolbarController` to rootView then navigation will not work and if I attach `AppToolbarController` to rootViewController then `navigationDrawer` transition will not work.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Your setup sounds like it is trying to combine more than one idea. So I am slightly confused, but from your issue's title "How to call pushViewController in NavigationDrawerController" - the code to call pushViewController from the NavigationDrawerController where the NavigationDrawerController.rootViewController is a NavigationController do this:

```
(navigationDrawerController?.rootViewController as? NavigationController)?.pushViewController(MyViewController(), animated: true)
```

Let me know how that works for you, all the best :)